# Code Optimization while creating Datetime instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a dropdownlist called ddlPayrollDate in my asp.net web site. I want to insert/bound dates 2 and 17 of last 3 months, including the current month. To consider when a year is changed, I had to write multiple conditions in my C# code which is given below is my code:

```
     ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(1, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime (DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, 17)));
                ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(2, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, 2)));
                if (DateTime.UtcNow.Month != 1)
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(3, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month - 1, 17)));
                else
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(3, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 1, 12, 17)));

                if (DateTime.UtcNow.Month != 1)
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(4, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month - 1, 2)));
                else
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(4, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 1, 12, 2)));

                if (DateTime.UtcNow.Month != 1 && DateTime.UtcNow.Month != 2)
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(5, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month - 2, 17)));
                else if (DateTime.UtcNow.Month == 1)
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(5, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 1, 11, 17)));
                else
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(5, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 1, 12, 17)));

                if (DateTime.UtcNow.Month != 1 && DateTime.UtcNow.Month != 2)
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(6, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month - 2, 2)));
                else if (DateTime.UtcNow.Month == 1)
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(6, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 1, 11, 2)));
                else
                    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(6, String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 1, 12, 2)));
```

Is there a way I can optimize this code without having these many conditions by using any datetime functions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you believe you're optimizing for? Readability and maintainability, I can see - but optimizing for performance would be rather different. Oh, and you could have some really odd times around midnight at the end of the month, as you're checking `UtcNow` several times, and it can change while this is executing...

Comment: @JonSkeet I actually wanted to optimize for readibility and maintainability..I am checking UtcNow because I wanted a common time zone for my website users belonging to sepearate time zones..

Comment: It's fine to check DateTime.UtcNow - but you should only access it *once* while you prepare everything. Otherwise you're using a moving target.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, I now see what you're saying! Yes, I shouldn't use it multiple times, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you want a loop. *Something* like:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
// Use the start of the month to avoid concerns around short months etc
DateTime current = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{        
    // Add the 17th... (add 16 days to the 1st)
    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(i * 2 + 1,
                                current.AddDays(16).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    // Add the 2nd... (add 1 day to the 1st)
    ddlPayrollDate.Items.Insert(i * 2 + 2,
                                current.AddDays(1).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    // Go back a month...
    current = current.AddMonths(-1);
}
```

This assumes that you always want the 17th and the 2nd of the *current* month (in UTC), whether the current day of month is before the 2nd, between the 2nd and the 17th, or after the 17th.

Also note that you should *usually* use the invariant culture when specifying a custom date format; or use a *standard* date format with a "normal" culture.

Comment: The thought of using a loop didn't come to my mind,basics! thanks for the reply..

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)

For example, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1) to get the date 1 month prior to today's date.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3);

for (Int32 indexer=0; indexer < 3; indexer++) {
  ddlPayrollDate.Items.Add(String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(startDate,Year, startDate.Month, 2)));
ddlPayrollDate.Items.Add(String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new DateTime(startDate,Year, startDate.Month, 17)));
startDate = startDate.AddMonth(1);
}
```